# Como incluir librerias externas js y css externos en Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tengo las siguientes librerias externas agregadas en mi codigo de la siguiente manera:

```
<!-- Datatables -->
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css"></script>
```

Yo tengo los archivos descargados de esa libreria listos para agregar a mi app. Lo que quisiera saber es como hacer para que me los tome, ya que los agregue en assets/stylesheets y assets/javascript y no me los toma mi aplicacion, es como si no los huibiese agregado. Muchas gracias. Dejo un ejemplo de uno de los archivos que agregue a la carpeta assets/styleshets

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor repasar [ask]. Tu pregunta necesita más detalles y acalaraciones. Si agregaste los archivos a la carpeta de `assets`, ¿Cómo los invocas desde tu aplicación? El navegador es el que se encarga de solicitar los recursos de tu aplicación, pero para eso debe saber qué recursos va a solicitar, para ello está el atributo `src`. ¿Has revisado en la consola del navegador para ver si te marca algún error? Si te marca error deberías agregarlo a tu pregunta. La imagen que publicas no aporta nada. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Ruby on Rails tiene su propia Gema para agregar datatables, pero también se pueden agregar tus estilos y scripts en la forma que lo estas haciendo:
Te muestro un ejemplo:

1. Agrega esos archivos la carpeta de assets

- /app/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js
- /app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.css

2. Editar el archivo application.html.erb para agregar las hojas de estilos y
   los scripts a toda la aplicacion.

`<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'bootstrap', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>`

`<%= javascript_include_tag 'bootstrap', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>`

3. Hay que modificar la configuracion, esto editando el archivo assets.rb ubicado.
   /config/initializers/assets.rb

`Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( bootstrap.js bootstrap.css )`

Y listo!!